# Retaining EntityManager Session during JAX-RS serialization

Tags: java, jpa, jax-rs, cdi

I have a simple JAX-RS Resource that serializes a view of a JPA entity. The JAX-RS Resource fetches the entity from a DAO, passes it through a bean mapper, then serializes the result. You'd think this was easy to implement.

Nope. Upon attempting to convert I get a LazyInitializationException. I have apparently lost the EntityManager session.

I had a workaround where I would enter a transaction from the JAX-RS Resource instead of on the DAO, to retain the same EntityManager, but this is leaving a bad taste in my mouth.

Using CDI, JPA, and JAX-RS, how would I go about retaining my EntityManager's session once I leave the Transaction started by the DAO?

Answer (score 1):

The goal of a DAO is to encapsulate and abstract the access to the data layer. So the DAO should provide exactly that data the consumer needs.

As your fetchType is lazy your DAO is only providing a part of the data with the information that there is more data which could be fetched from the database. Fetching the data fails without an active session.

You have two choices:

1. As you tried entering the transaction from JAX-RS resource but this would reduce your DAO to absurdity. In this case I'd simply delete the DAO and inject the EntityManager in the JAX-RS resource.
2. Use your DAO as it's intended and initialize all the data the consumer expects. This can be done with [Hibernate.initialize(entity)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize(java.lang.Object)) or some helper method which iterates over the missing entities and simply calls `entity.getId()` on each of them.

Comment: At this point the function of my DAO is mostly to encapsulate some search logic: find by name, collection containing X. Should I be reducing these to helper methods instead?

Comment: If a DAO is senseful depends on many things - not least which religion you want to follow. If your DAO is used by other services too I'd add some methods which initialize more data.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that your DAO should return an entity which already has all the needed relations initialized. JAX-RS Resource's role should be only to serialize whatever you give it, it shouldn't worry about lazy relations.

Comment: Other services need to use the same DAO and if they don't require the data, it is a waste to eagerly load it every time.

Comment: It would be a waste to mark the lazy collections as eager, but you can have different DAO methods for different purposes, even if they basically do the same thing. In a similar situation, our service methods (beside basic parameters such as `id` if you query the object by id) also accepted a configuration object which held information on what relations need to be initialized. This way you can use the same method in various scenarios, without the overhead.

Comment: If you extensively using JsonView it would be hell to initialize every lazy property based on your view. Whole beauty of JsonView is that it returns subset of properties and if that property Lazily initialized then you optimize automatically your DB queries. Cilph question is very much valid.